# Does a purchased iTunes song contain my Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id, itunes-store

Do the files that I download (purchased) from iTunes contain references to my Apple ID? Could you (or anyone else) know what Apple ID purchased the song just by having the .m4a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Purchased .m4a files contain the purchaser's name & email address used in the related Apple ID.

A quick way round it is to just re-encode them as AAC.

With iTunes in Music view, My music

- right click the column header & make sure 'Kind' is showing.
- click that column to sort by Kind
- scroll to find 'Protected AAC' songs.
- right-click/Get Info [or  <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>   <kbd>i</kbd>  ] then see the File tab [iTunes 12] or the Summary tab [iTunes 11 or earlier] This will show the purchaser info.

To remove...

- Preferences > General > Import Settings... Make sure it's set to AAC Encoder (& iTunes Plus for better quality)

Then for each protected song...

- right click or File Menu - Create AAC Version.

Then delete the old protected versions. You'll have to do that alphabetically, as in your current sort view, they won't show in the same place in the list.

---

Examples of tagging before & after re-encoding as AAC...
Incidentally, it was proved empirically back in 2007 that the audio itself contains no watermark. [EFF: DRM-free iTunes files carry “more than just names and e-mail addresses”](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2007/05/eff-drm-free-itunes-files-carry-more-than-just-names-and-e-mail-addresses/)

Before - from iTunes Store
 <sup>I've blurred anything that could possibly be identifying</sup>
[image]

After...

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this remove the tag? Isn’t it [watermarked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_watermarking)?

Comment: m4p were watermarked; m4a it's just a tag. Try it & see.

Comment: Thank you - it's not that I want to remove the tags, I don't mind (on the contrary, as a DJ, it's easier to prove I have purchased my music when an inspector comes by). I was wondering if someone "took" my music and shared it illegally, I would get in trouble. So I suppose yes, since the files can be traced back to me.

Comment: Yes, it's always nice to be able to prove ownership - though if someone sneaked a USB into your machine & made off with songs, it would be nigh-on impossible to prove it was theft.

Comment: Well, as I have no idea how the m4a files would be watermarked, I hardly can.

Comment: Apparently, it's an ID3tag. Using Mp3Tag you can remove them:
http://i.imgur.com/aoywtuX.png

Comment: @Édouard - I'll do your homework for you. ID tags for before & after on one of the recent U2 tracks, added to my Answer.

Comment: The problem with this solution means that the audio is degraded as it is recompressed lossily.