# How to remove my email address, name, and purchase date from iTunes Plus files?

Tags: itunes, music, file-conversion, privacy, m4a

Any files that you purchase from iTunes (or obtain with iTunes Match) will contain your personal information:

[image: m4a personal information blurred]

Is there a script that automatically goes through all music inside the iTunes Media folder and anonymizes `.m4a` (iTunes AAC) files to [EFF](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2007/06/privatunes-0-9-does-not-anonymize-itunes-plus-files)-standards?

While also meeting the following requirements:

- Not trans/re-encoding (and thus losing quality)
- Keep the same file format
- Keep play counts, import date, etc.
- Keep songs organized in playlists as they are

I have thousands of purchased iTunes songs, so going one-by-one is not an option.

Comment: Maybe not a dupe, but similar to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156538/does-a-purchased-itunes-song-contain-my-apple-id/156543#156543

Comment: Moved to Spotify instead... that solved it :D